# cron – screen doesn’t work if has a command to run

Tags: cron, gnu-screen

If I set a `cron` job as below everything works: the new screen session is started and I can access it later.

```
* * * * * screen -d -m -S test
```

But if the `cron` entry is as below, the screen session is not started or at least is not retrievable (`screen -ls` doesn’t find it).

```
* * * * * screen -d -m -S test date
* * * * * screen -d -m -S test bash -c “date”
```

If I run any of the above straight from the command line, everything works as expected.
But I tried any combination of commands I could think of and none worked, so I’m clearly missing something.

Comment: If you want append date to test test, yo must quote your date command with ` : `screen -d -m -S test`\` `date`\`

Comment: I’m using ‘date’ as test code, matter of fact I’d be passing a much longer command with n params as well, something like ‘/path/to/cmd start -s —name=test’ ‘. Either way, wrapping the cmd in ‘s also didn’t work.

Comment: With something like your first example it'll generate a new session every minute. Is that really what you want, or did you mean `@reboot screen -d -m -S test`?

Answer (score 3):

You can not reattach to the started `screen` session because it has already exited. When you give a command to `screen`, it will run that command and exit immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Screens are a per user. Crons are background scheduled tasks. If you need to know the output of a particular cron you're better off outputting to a file or telling it to email you.

Bodging it to run a screen session isnt really what thats for IMO.

Comment: I know, but in this specific scenario I’m trying to start a daemon process interactively, so that it will be up and running @reboot and I will be later able to access its console.

Comment: Indeed i see what you're trying to achieve but a cron is not what thats for. You should have something in /etc/init.d and use your system init and run levels to start it on boot

Comment: You could put it in a bash script and create a service for it

Comment: That was my first option, but it doesn’t appear to be working either... that’s why I resorted to a cron job, to al least get it going for now.. guess I’ll stick with init.d until I figure it out.  Still I don’t get why the cron command would fail like that?

Comment: What I mean is, the problem seem to be related to screen not accepting the command, rather than the fact I’m trying to do this via cron and not initd.

Comment: Hmm you should set the crontab to email you output results and hopefully it should give you an error

Comment: I already piped it with `cmd >>/path/to/logfile 2>&1` to no avail. But shouldn’t this be expected from a detached screen session?

Comment: Hmmm try this instead: MAILTO="email@domain.com"

Comment: At the line above

Comment: There’s no need, I tested that piping and it works with other commands from cron... also the machine has no connection, let alone a mail configured.

Comment: Ah okay fair enough ill do some testing see if i can get you a fix

Comment: No worries man, I’ll figure it out sometimes or hopefully somebody else will come along with some ideas! Thanks a lot for your help anyway :)